# Wrong size of canvas when set by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

When setting the size of a `canvas` inside a `div` by Javascript I always end up with a wrong layout. This doesn't happen when I replace the inner `canvas` with a `div`.

In the below case

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <canvas class="inner"></canvas>
</div>
```

with the following JS code

```
canvas.style.width = `${element.clientWidth}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${element.clientHeight}px`;
```

the inner `canvas` forces the outer `div` to show scrollbars. This is not the case when replacing the canvas with a `div`.

Here is an [example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45q86b4t/). It ends up with not expected scrollbars. [And here is the exact same thing](https://jsfiddle.net/pby0rpn8/) with a `div` instead of a `canvas` showing no scrollbars as expected.

Comment: Add overflow:hidden; to the .outerdiv style to resolve for canvas

Comment: Just give display:block; to the canvas.